# How to open a excel file after it gets downloaded in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, browser

I download an excel file (.xls) by using below code:

JavaScript Code:

`window.location = result.filename;`

After downloading, I want to open a excel file automatically  without clicking on it. I want JavaScript code for opening excel file automatically.

I tested with following function code. But it runs only in Internet Explorer, not in Mozilla, Chrome...

```
function openExcelFile(strFilePath) {
var objExcel;
objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
objExcel.Visible = true;
objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath);
}
```

By using above code, the excel file open automatically after it gets downloaded in Internet Explorer.

I want JavaScript code for opening excel file automatically after downloaded by working in all browsers.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: does it shows any error in mozilla or chrome for not opening the excel file

Comment: Cannot able to open excel file in mozilla , chrome...It shows error. Because ActiveXObject doesnot supported in chrome, mozilla .

Comment: How do you get the path that the user saved the file?

Answer (score 0):

pass the excel file path to the controller. it will works fine with all browsers.

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string path)
{

    string extension = new FileInfo(path).Extension;
    if (extension != null || extension != string.Empty)
    {
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls":
                return File(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
            case ".xlsx":
                return File(path, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        }
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: I use this code. I get "Your browser doesnot support this.". Because the ActiveXObject doesnot support in chrome, mozilla. I want to open a excel file automatically supported in all browsers. Please help me.

Comment: @NivithaG sorry. there is no ActiveXObject  support in chrome and firefox. why should you can download and display the excel sheet from server side through c# code.

Comment: How can I download and display the excel sheet from server side through c# code mvc?

Comment: how you loading excel sheets in your projects